# rolling a seven when at least one die is a four?

Tags: probability, dice

I have been working on some stuff like this and I am fairly confused,   I wrote some code to see how it works when simulated and I am further from an answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

double ROLLS = 10000000.0;
int count = 0;
Dice a = new Dice(6);
Dice b = new Dice(6);

for (int i = 0; i < ROLLS; i++) {
  a.roll();
  b.roll();
  if (a.getDots() == 4 || b.getDots() == 4)
    if (a.getDots() + b.getDots() == 7)
      count++;
}
System.out.println(count/ROLLS + "\n1/6 = .1666 \n 1/12 = .083333");
}
```

Im getting about 1/12 every time I run it and I am confused as to how this is possible.  Thank you!

edit: sorry, programmers mind :P

Basically, if I were to roll two dies, at the same time, and ensure that AT LEAST ONE of the dies are a four, what is the probability that the sum of the two dies will be 7?

Comment: This isn't a website fore programmers, I have no idea what that code does, could you state your question without it?

Comment: Edited, Forgot that this wasn't stack overflow.

Comment: I feel I should point out that 1/11 $\neq$ .083333. That's 1/12. 1/11 $\approx$ 0.0909091.

Comment: good catch... Woops

Comment: Your code, as it stands, is trying to calculate the probability of (4,3) or (3,4) out of all probabilities, because you're dividing by the total number of rolls rather than the number of rolls satisfying the first condition. You need to add a second count outside the inner "if" and find the ratio of the two counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many have at least one 4? how many don't? If they don't there are 5 options for each digit. So there are 25 that don't. we know there are 36 total, so 36-25 do, which is 11.

only (3,4) and (4,3) add up 7 and have a 4. So the answer is $\frac{2}{11}$